# jdbc connection error

Tags: java, jdbc, google-sheets-api

I would like to fill in a google spreadsheet cell with the output of a mysql database query, so I've written this simple script following the example in the google tutorial:

```
function get_tbs_number() {
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:9008/icadata");
    var stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.setMaxRows(100);
    var start = new Date();
    var rs = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from CNGSfiltered where run=10269 and (GTO1>4 or GTO2>4 or GTO3>4 or GTO4>4);");
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
    cell.offset(0, 0).setValue(rs.getString(1));
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
    var end = new Date();
    Logger.log("time took: " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
```

The problem is that when I try to run the script a get an error connecting to the database, while the connection to the same database from command line (mysql -h localhost -P 9008 -u # -p# icadata) does work.

Comment: can you post some more information like a stack trace?

Comment: You mixing Java and Javascript?

Comment: Do you run this code inside a web browser? Do you try to connect to mysql database from your local machine?

Comment: I'm running this script in the Google Spreadsheet, using google Java API, so I think I'm not supposed to explicitly load JDBC driver. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc_overview. The error I get is something like. "Error trying to connect to database. Check the connection string".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Google cannot reach `127.0.0.1`.  Try opening up your mysql port (9008) on your router. Then use www.whatismyip.com to get your public IP address.

```
"jdbc:mysql://<myPublicIP>:9008/icadata"
```

You will then likely have to run a sql grant command that includes googles IP's or use % (not very secure).

```
grant all on icadata.* to '<user>'@'<google ips>' identified by '<password>';
```

Good luck! Here's some reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc